# Sort Column without using Select Statement

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sorting

I am new to this and I have looked all over.  Sorry if this question is a repeat.

I have modified a Wordpress page to return custom results from the wpdb.  The table has 9 columns, and the last two are derived from math calculations, so nothing is actually stored in the database.  I would like to sort DESC by the last two columns, but not sure how to do this as it is not calculated in the SELECT statement.

The first column numbers the rows automatically.  The next 6 columns retrieves information from the wp_posts table.

The last two columns (which I want to sort by) are calculated using meta data stored in wp_postmeta.

This is the SELECT statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'eafl_link' AND post_status = 'publish'"; $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And these are the results in an HTML table:

```
     echo "<tbody><tr>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . $counter . "</td>"; 
 echo "<td class='center'>" . "<a href=\"" . $results->post_name . "\" . target='_blank'>"    . $results->post_title . '</a>' . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . date("Y/m/j", strtotime($results->post_modified)) . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eafltime',true) . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflmin',true) . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflmax',true) . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflref',true) . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . round(get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflmin',true)*get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflref',true))/100 . "</td>";
 echo "<td class='center'>" . round(get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflmin',true)*get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eaflref',true)/get_post_meta( $results->ID,'claim-eafltime',true))/100 . "</td>";
```

The last two columns produce the correct data, but I would like to sort the entire table by their returned values, DESC.

Like I said, I'm very, very new at this and I consider myself lucky that the table and math even works at all - to be able to initially sort by one or more of these columns would be icing on the cake.

Also, I'm probably vulnerable to SQL-injection, influenza, and everything else.  Suggests are appreciated.

Thank you, all.  Any help would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: "9 columns", "last 2 is math calculations", "nothing is actually stored in database". But then "SELECT * ...". It means you have the data stored in wp_posts, at least derived calculated values and those last fields must have names that you can use at the end your SQL string like "ORDER BY lastField1 DESC, lastField2 DESC".

Comment: @smozgur Thanks for the reply.  I had previously used the following SELECT statement with dummy columns in the wp_posts table to test that math, and it worked fine: 'code'trim(round(claim_min * claim_ref)/100)+0 as best, trim(round(claim_min * claim_ref / claim_time)/100)+0 as recommend.....
ORDER BY recommend DESC, best DESC";'code' As you say works in the SELECT, but only if I query the wp_posts table.  Is there a way to recode this so that it selects and applies the math calculation from the appropriate columns from the wp_metaposts table instead?  I would prefer to draw from that table.

Comment: I am not familiar with with the wp table structure and I tried to help by looking at the query you posted. Assuming wp_metaposts table has a key matching with the id in posts table: so you just need to create a join to get the necessary fields from meta table and do the math as you need. I can likely do that if I knew the table structures and also your math properly but I just noticed wordpress tag in your question. Perhaps a WordPress expert might help better.